# Set a new Template of Product type options: Text, Select, Date

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template

I tried to set a new template of **Product options type** (`text.phtml`, `select.phtml`, `date.phtml` )but it doesn't work !

**Catalog.xml**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
    </block>
    ...
</block>
```

**My xml:**

```
//for a text.phtml
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_options_type_text">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>path/to/new/text.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution, I simply copy the piece of xml in `local.xml` and i set the new Path like this:

**local.xml**

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>new/path/text.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>new/path/select.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>new/path/date.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```